Typeorm issue with ordering when column name is upper cased
I have CourseEntity like this:
@Entity()
export class CourseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => BoughtCourseEntity, (boughtCourse) => boughtCourse.course)
  boughtCourses!: Array<BoughtCourseEntity>;

  @Column({ select: false, insert: false, readonly: true, nullable: true })
  boughtCoursesCount: number;

  constructor(partial: Partial<CourseEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}


In my query builder I want to do sorting by boughtCoursesCount like this:
  const query = this._courseRepository.createQueryBuilder('course');
    query.addSelect((subQuery) => {
      return subQuery
        .select('coalesce(COUNT(bc.id), 0)', 'boughtCoursesCount')
        .from('bought_course_entity', 'bc')
        .where('bc.courseId = course.id');
    }, 'course_boughtCoursesCount');

    return pagination(data, query, ['course.name'], {
      default: 'course.updatedAt',
      createdAt: 'course.createdAt',
      updatedAt: 'course.updatedAt',
      price: 'course.price',
      boughtCoursesCount: 'course.boughtCoursesCount',
    });

where in pagination I do the following for sorting:
  const sort = data.sort ? data.sort.split(':') : null;
  query.orderBy(
    sort ? sortPossibilities[sort[0]] : sortPossibilities['default'],
    sort ? (sort[1] == 'ASC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC') : 'ASC',
  );

The raw query I've got is:
SELECT "course"."id" AS "course_id", (SELECT COUNT("bc"."id") AS "boughtCoursesCount" FROM "bought_course_entity" "bc" WHERE ( "bc"."courseId" = "course"."id" ) AND ( "bc"."deletedAt" IS NULL )) AS "course_boughtCoursesCount" FROM "course_entity" "course" WHERE "course"."deletedAt" IS NULL ORDER BY "course"."boughtCoursesCount" DESC

and the result in pgadmin4 is
enter image description here
So there is no errors but sorting does not work...
How to fix that? When I change everywhere boughtCoursesCount to boughtcoursescount then everything works fine... Any ideas?

You have a real column called boughtCoursesCount, and you're also making a virtual column called boughtCoursesCount here select('coalesce(COUNT(bc.id), 0)', 'boughtCoursesCount').
